# Capture a value output by a stored procedure in the calling T-SQL script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm building unit tests in my database project. I have a stored procedure that I'm building tests for that is used in a script task in an SSIS package. The result set is mapped to one of the package variables.

I'm not sure how I can find that variable result in my unit test script?

This is the stored procedure. It's the `AppInstanceID` I'd like to capture:

```
Create Procedure [log].LogStartOfApplication
    @ApplicationName varchar(255)
As
 declare @ErrMsg varchar(255)
 declare @AppID int = (Select ApplicationID From cfg.Applications Where ApplicationName = @ApplicationName)

If (@AppID Is Null)
    begin
        set @ErrMsg = 'Cannot find ApplicationName ' + Coalesce(@ApplicationName, '<NULL>')
        raiserror(@ErrMsg,16,1)
        return-1
    end

Insert Into [log].SSISAppInstance
    (ApplicationID, StartDateTime, Status)
    Output inserted.AppInstanceID
    Values
    (@AppID, GetDate(), 'Running')
```

And this is my unit test script:

```
-- database unit test for log.LogStartOfApplication
DECLARE @RC AS INT, @ApplicationName AS VARCHAR (255);

SELECT @RC = 0,
       @ApplicationName = 'Unit Test Application';

EXECUTE @RC = [log].[LogStartOfApplication] @ApplicationName;

SELECT @RC AS RC;
```

I thought that the value would be returned into the `@RC` variable but of course it isn't. Is there a way to capture the result set in my `@RC` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a stored procedure with an OUTPUT parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)